# MySQL outer join with a pivot table

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE link (
    entityid integer,
    fileid INT (11) NULL,
    folderid INT (11) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE file (
    fileid integer,
    name varchar
);    

CREATE TABLE folder (
    folderid integer,
    name varchar
);
```

I want to get list of files and folder attached to an entity. Have tried below query however it gives null records if there is no record in either folder or file

```
select fi.name,fo.name 
FROM link ll
LEFT OUTER JOIN file fi ON lk.FileId = fi.FileId  
LEFT OUTER JOIN folder fo ON lk.FileId = fo.FileId  
WHERE dl.entityid = 307
```

sample data

```
link        
entityid    fileid  folderid
22          1       null
22          2       null
22          3       null
22          4       null
22          null    33


file    
fileid  name
1       file1
2       file2
3       file3
4       file4

folder  
folderid    name
33         folder33
34         folder34
35         folder35
36         folder36
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `entityid` to the select clause:

```
SELECT ll.entityid, fi.name, fo.name 
FROM link ll
LEFT OUTER JOIN file fi ON lk.FileId = fi.FileId  
LEFT OUTER JOIN folder fo ON lk.FileId = fo.FileId  
WHERE dl.entityid = 307;
```

Comment: @FullStack77 it's normal the result is null. You want the files and folder where the entityid=307, but there is no link with that entityid.

Comment: try with 22 for your query..also in your query u have assumed fo have fileid column which is not the case

Comment: @FullStack77 if you look closely at your sample data you will find that field in two of your tables. So what did I assume?